# android-maven-gradle-plugin + gradle-experimental

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-maven-plugin, gradle-experimental

In my android library project I use `com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5` to install my library to my local maven repo, and this has always worked fine. Now, for various NDK related reasons I have had to switch to the [gradle-experimental-0.8.2 plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental). This version of the gradle plugin uses a new syntax, with e.g. `model` blocks surrounding the `android` blocks.

The problem is, when using this new syntax I am unable to get my maven artifact tasks to work, for example the `sourcesJar` task that is taken straight from the examples:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}
```

This no longer works because there is no block `android`. I assumed I simply had to change to the new syntax, such as `model.android.sources.main.java.source.srcDirs`, but with no luck. In fact, it says `could not get unknown property 'android' for task 'lib:model' of type org.gradle.api.reporting.model.ModelReport`.

I also have simpler statements such as

```
version = android.defaultConfig.versionName
```

This also doesn't work neither with `android.defaultConfig` nor `model.android.defaultConfig`.

What am I doing wrong here? It feels like I have misunderstood how gradle/groovy works fundamentally when I am unable to reference variables defined in blocks like I used to do with the stable gradle version. I thought the `android` block was simply moved one level of indirection down, inside `model` blocks, so why can't I reference things like `model.android.defaultConfig.versionName`?